# Are non-English characters allowed in Amazon S3 filenames?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Are you allowed to use non-English characters in filenames on Amazon S3? I couldn't find any docs about filename requirements.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)

> You can use any UTF-8 character in an object key name. However, using certain characters in key names can cause problems with some applications and protocols. The following guidelines help you maximize compliance with DNS, web-safe characters, XML parsers, and other APIs.

They encourage not to use non alphanumeric characters (apart from a few specific ones).

Comment: Many thanks, it was exactly what i was looking for. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)